# High values of r^2 and residual sum of squares

Tags: regression

The table below shows the average time T it takes for a computer to sort n items

n (items)             5      10      50      100    500      1000

T (microseconds)    17.4    28.2    157.6   305.5   2812.9  9701.0

Use your graphics calculator to fit a quadratic model to the data.

The value of r^2 for the quad model is 0.9999519 (indicating a strong fit). However, the SS(res) is coming out to be 3552 (which is very high indicating not a good fit).

Could someone please help with this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.